# IF transformer color codes

Tags: transformer, inductor, radio, colour-coding, tuner

Is there any standard color code available for IF transformers?

Generally in most of the Japanese radio receivers I see *red* color slug for MW oscillator, *white* and *yellow* slugs in AM IF stage, *orange* color slug for FM oscillator, *blue*, *purple* and *pink* colored slugs in FM IF stage, etc.

Comment: Have you tried looking at suppliers sites to see if there is any consistency between suppliers?

Comment: As per my observations most of the IF transformers may not have any marking / symbols to identify the manufacturer(s).

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard that I've found, unfortunately.  But, there are some common conventions.

This page has more detailed information than most pages I've found on the subject:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.com/filters/if-amplifier-transformers.htm

It includes turns ratios, impedances, intended application, core color, etc., for a small sample of IF transformers.  The general advice on that page is to consult the datasheet for the part number, if you can find it.  Of course, most of the time there is no part number to be found.

An LCR meter can help identify the winding inductances in a transformer.